# Giving a regular language $L$ so that $K_L = \{x\,|\,∃y\,|\,(x \sim y \,\land\, y \in L)\}$ is not regular

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $\{a,b\}$ the alphabet $\Sigma$. The relation $\sim$ is defined on $\{a,b\}^*$ by $x \sim y$ if $x$ and $y$ have the same number of a's and b's. If $L$ is a language on alphabet $\Sigma$ then
$$K_L = \{x\,|\,∃y\,|\,(x \sim y \,\land\, y \in L)\}$$
So, from my understanding, a word $x \in K_L$ if it can be rearranged to form a word from $L$.
But what kind of language $L$ can be given so that $K_L$ is non regular ? I can't seem to find an answer to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language $\{\epsilon,ab,abab,ababab,\ldots\}$ is regular ($S\to abS\mid\epsilon$) but the set of all words that have the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s isn't.

Comment: Definitely context-free: $S\to a S b S \mid b S a S \mid \epsilon$

Comment: @rici Nice! I wish I had studied languages in a class instead of self-studying some Dover book or other....